# Lookup and group from two fields in one aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation that looks like this:

```
userSchema.statics.getCounts = function (req, type) {
  return this.aggregate([
    { $match: { organization: req.user.organization._id } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'tickets', localField: `${type}Tickets`, foreignField: '_id', as: `${type}_tickets`,
      },
    },
    { $unwind: `$${type}_tickets` },
    { $match: { [`${type}_tickets.createdAt`]: { $gte: new Date(moment().subtract(4, 'd').startOf('day').utc()), $lt: new Date(moment().endOf('day').utc()) } } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          groupDate: {
            $dateFromParts: {
              year: { $year: `$${type}_tickets.createdAt` },
              month: { $month: `$${type}_tickets.createdAt` },
              day: { $dayOfMonth: `$${type}_tickets.createdAt` },
            },
          },
          userId: `$${type}_tickets.assignee_id`,
        },
        ticketCount: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { '_id.groupDate': -1 },
    },
    { $group: { _id: '$_id.userId', data: { $push: { groupDate: '$_id.groupDate', ticketCount: '$ticketCount' } } } },
  ]);
};
```

Which outputs data like this:

```
[ 
  {
    _id: 5aeb6b71709f43359e0888bb,
    data: [ 
      { "groupDate": 2018-05-07T00:00:000Z", ticketCount: 4 }
  }
]
```

Ideally though, I would have data like this:

```
[ 
  {
    _id: 5aeb6b71709f43359e0888bb,
    data: [ 
      { "groupDate": 2018-05-07T00:00:000Z", assignedCount: 4, resolvedCount: 8 }
  }
]
```

The difference being that the object for the user would output both the total number of assigned tickets and the total number of resolved tickets for each date.

My userSchema is like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  assignedTickets: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Ticket',
      index: true,
    },
  ],
  resolvedTickets: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Ticket',
      index: true,
    },
  ],
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

An example user doc is like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5aeb6b71709f43359e0888bb", 
    "assignedTickets": ["5aeb6ba7709f43359e0888bd", "5aeb6bf3709f43359e0888c2", "5aec7e0adcdd76b57af9e889"], 
    "resolvedTickets": ["5aeb6bc2709f43359e0888be", "5aeb6bc2709f43359e0888bf"], 
    "firstName": "Name", 
    "lastName": "Surname", 
}
```

An example ticket doc is like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5aeb6ba7709f43359e0888bd", 
    "ticket_id": 120292, 
    "type": "assigned", 
    "status": "Pending", 
    "assignee_email": "email@gmail.com", 
    "assignee_id": "5aeb6b71709f43359e0888bb", 
    "createdAt": "2018-05-02T20:05:59.147Z", 
    "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T20:05:59.147Z", 
}
```

I've tried adding multiple lookups and group stages, but I keep getting an empty array. If I only do one lookup and one group, I get the correct counts for the searched on field, but I'd like to have both fields in one query. Is it possible to have the query group on two lookups?

Comment: It would help your question if you could produce a small sample of documents from which the expected result can be obtained. Then people can actually use that in just same way you can to demonstrate how to return the desired result. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is something in the help center we do expect you to read, and will help you get better and more timely answers to your questions.

Comment: Question updated with an example user doc and an example ticket doc.

Comment: It's better, but really you should be showing what "reproduces the expected results". For example if you expect to see `assignedCount: 4, resolvedCount: 8` then the documents you include in the question should contain sufficient information to be able to "reproduce" that result. It also helps you show the documents as viewed from the [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/), because then people can simply copy and paste the content and use it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short you seem to be coming to terms with setting up your models in mongoose and have gone overboard with references. In reality you really should not keep the arrays within the `"User"` documents. This is actually an "anti-pattern" which was just something mongoose used initially as a convention for keeping "references" for population where it did not understand how to translate the references from being kept in the "child" to the "parent" instead.

You actually have that data in each `"Ticket"` and the natural form of `$lookup` is to use that `"foreignField"` in reference to the detail from the local collection. In this case the `"assignee_id"` on the tickets will suffice for looking at matching back to the `"_id"` of the `"User"`. Though you don't state it, your `"status"` should be an indicator of whether the data is actually either "assigned" as when in "Pending" state or "resolved" when it is not.

For the sake of simplicity we are going to consider the state "resolved" if it is anything other than "Pending" in value, but extending on the logic from the example for actual needs is not the problem here.

Basically then we resolve to a **single** [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operation by actually using the natural "foreign key" as opposed to keeping separate arrays.

### MongoDB 3.6 and greater

Ideally you would use features from MongoDB 3.6 with sub-pipeline processing here:

```
// Better date calculations
const oneDay = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
var now = Date.now(),
    end = new Date((now - (now % oneDay)) + oneDay),
    start = new Date(end.valueOf() - (4 * oneDay));

User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "organization": req.user.organization._id } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Ticket.collection.name,
    "let": { "id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "createdAt": { "$gte": start, "$lt": end },
        "$expr": {
          "$eq": [ "$$id", "$assignee_id" ]
        }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "status": "$status",
          "date": {
            "$dateFromParts": {
              "year": { "$year": "$createdAt" },
              "month": { "$month": "$createdAt" },
              "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$createdAt" }
            }
          }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.date",
        "data": {
          "$push": {
            "k": {
              "$cond": [
                { "$eq": ["$_id.status", "Pending"] },
                "assignedCount",
                "resolvedCount"
              ]
            },
            "v": "$count"
          }
        }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },
      { "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            { "groupDate": "$_id", "assignedCount": 0, "resolvedCount": 0 },
            { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "data"
  }},
  { "$project": { "data": 1 } }
])
```

### From MongoDB 3.0 and upwards

Or where you lack those features we use a different pipeline process and a little data transformation after the results are returned from the server:

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "organization": req.user.organization._id } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Ticket.collection.name,
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "assignee_id",
    "as": "data"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$match": {
    "data.createdAt": { "$gte": start, "$lt": end }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { 
      "userId": "$_id",
      "date": {
        "$add": [
          { "$subtract": [
            { "$subtract": [ "$data.createdAt", new Date(0) ] },
            { "$mod": [
              { "$subtract": [ "$data.createdAt", new Date(0) ] },
              oneDay
            ]}
          ]},
          new Date(0)
        ]
      },
      "status": "$data.status"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "userId": "$_id.userId",
      "date": "$_id.date"
    },
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$_id.status", "Pending" ] },
            "assignedCount",
            "resolvedCount"
          ]
        },
        "v": "$count"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id.userId": 1, "_id.date": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.userId",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "groupDate": "$_id.date",
        "data": "$data"
      }
    }
  }}
])
.then( results => 
  results.map( ({ data, ...d }) => 
    ({
      ...d,
      data: data.map(di =>
        ({
          groupDate: di.groupDate,
          assignedCount: 0,
          resolvedCount: 0,
          ...di.data.reduce((acc,curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.k]: curr.v }),{})
        })
      )
    })
  )
)
```

Which just really goes to show that even with the fancy features in modern releases, you really don't need them because there pretty much has always been ways to work around this. Even the JavaScript parts just had slightly longer winded versions before the current "object spread" syntax was available.

So that is really the direction you need to go in. What you certainly don't want is using "multiple" [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stages or even applying [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) conditions on what could potentially be large arrays. Also both forms here do their best to "filter down" the number of items "joined" from the foreign collection so as not to cause a breach of the BSON limit.

Particularly the "pre 3.6" version actually has a trick where `$lookup + $unwind + $match` occur in succession which you can see in the explain output. All stages actually combine into "one" stage there which solely returns only the items which match the conditions in the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) from the foreign collection. Keeping things "unwound" until we reduce further avoids BSON limit problems, as does the new form with MongoDB 3.6 where the "sub-pipeline" does all the document reduction and grouping before any results are returned.

Your **one** document sample would return like this:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeb6b71709f43359e0888bb"),
        "data" : [
            {
                "groupDate" : ISODate("2018-05-02T00:00:00Z"),
                "assignedCount" : 1,
                "resolvedCount" : 0

            }
        ]
    }
```

Once I expand the date selection to include that date, which of course the date selection can also be improved and corrected from your original form.

So it seems to make sense that your relationships are actually defined that way but it's just that you recorded them "twice". You don't need to and even if that's not the definition then you should actually instead record on the "child" rather than an array in the parent. We can juggle and merge the parent arrays, but that's counterproductive to actually establishing the data relations correctly and using them correctly as well.

Comment: Neil, I appreciate the well thought out answer! I originally had the data structured differently and moved to a model with a ticket schema and didn't consider that it's not necessary to keep references on the User schema, when the Ticket schema references the User already. I agree that this is a better approach and reduces a lot of unnecessary complexity. Your detailed answer is very much appreciated, as I'm sure it will help reduce headaches down the line!

Comment: @Josh No problem. You also might want to look at setting up ["virtuals" for convenience of reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) through the rest of the mongoose code. I'd generally recommend sticking with `$lookup` for the data retrieval, but the occasional additional query from the virtual won't hurt that much.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
db.users.aggregate([  
   {  
      $lookup:{ // lookup assigned tickets
         from:'tickets',
         localField:'assignedTickets',
         foreignField:'_id',
         as:'assigned',

      }
   },
   {  
      $lookup:{ // lookup resolved tickets 
         from:'tickets',
         localField:'resolvedTickets',
         foreignField:'_id',
         as:'resolved',

      }
   },
   {  
      $project:{  
         "tickets":{  // merge all tickets into one single array
            $concatArrays:[  
               "$assigned",
               "$resolved"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $unwind:'$tickets' // flatten the 'tickets' array into separate documents
   },
   {  
      $group:{ // group by 'createdAt' and 'assignee_id'
         _id:{  
            groupDate:{  
               $dateFromParts:{  
                  year:{ $year:'$tickets.createdAt' },
                  month:{ $month:'$tickets.createdAt' },
                  day:{ $dayOfMonth:'$tickets.createdAt' },

               },
            },
            userId:'$tickets.assignee_id',
         },
         assignedCount:{ // get the count of assigned tickets
            $sum:{  
               $cond:[  
                  {  // by checking the 'type' field for a value of 'assigned'
                     $eq:[  
                        '$tickets.type',
                        'assigned'
                     ]
                  },
                  1, // if matching count 1
                  0 // else 0
               ]
            }
         },
         resolvedCount:{  
            $sum:{  
               $cond:[  
                  {  // by checking the 'type' field for a value of 'resolved'
                     $eq:[  
                        '$tickets.type',
                        'resolved'
                     ]
                  },
                  1, // if matching count 1
                  0 // else 0
               ]
            }
         },
      },
   },
   {  
      $sort:{  // sort by 'groupDate' descending
         '_id.groupDate':-1
      },
   },
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:'$_id.userId', // group again but only by userId
         data:{  
            $push:{  // create an array
               groupDate:'$_id.groupDate',
               assignedCount:{ 
                  $sum:'$assignedCount'
               },
               resolvedCount:{  
                  $sum:'$resolvedCount'
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: `+10` for your effort

Comment: If I use like this, the second lookup is always empty.